# Пунктуация во "внутренней" прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Подскажите правильную расстановку знаков препинания в данном предложении с внутренней прямой речью.

> Как только мне становилось хорошо и я начинал думать *ах, как же
>   хорошо* жизнь снова окунала меня в грязь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правила (по Розенталю) [§122. Прямая речь внутри авторских слов](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Кроме классической прямой речи **с наибольшей выделительной способностью**, существуют другие способы оформления дословных высказываний.

Постановка запятой или тире зависит **от вида прямой речи** (повествовательная, вопросительная, восклицательная).

1) **Встроенная прямая речь, нет тире**: Как только мне становилось хорошо и я начинал думать: «Ах, как же хорошо»,  жизнь снова окунала меня в грязь.

2) **Тире при наличии восклицательной  интонации**: "Как только мне становилось хорошо и я начинал думать: «Ах, как же хорошо!» –   жизнь снова окунала меня в грязь.

3) Дословное высказывание **в качестве члена предложения (дополнения)**: Как только мне становилось хорошо и я начинал думать "ах, как же хорошо!", жизнь снова окунала меня в грязь.

**Примеры:**

Софья Карловна еще раз поцеловала Маню и, сказав ей: «Поди, гуляй, моя крошка», сама поплелась за свои ширмы.

И только когда он шептал: «Мама! Мама!» – ему становилось как будто легче...

Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича. С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

Comment: Спасибо. Вот Вы оказались правы!

Comment: @Arina, с первыми двумя пунктами согласен. А вот насчет третьего сомневаюсь. Поскольку в нашем примере нет никаких высказываний, это внутреняя речь, невысказнные мысли.

Comment: Серж, мне кажется, что при выборе варианта оформления прямой речи важна структура предложения и желание  автора (1)  выделять или не выделять  прямую речь по классическим правилам (а это особая интонация, остановка в речи) или (2) сделать высказывание простым членом предложения.

Comment: Там есть ссылка на первоисточник Примечание. Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Гоголь); Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», все больше собирало сторонников (Фадеев); Он вспомнил пословицу «Не плюй в колодец...» и отошел в сторону; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

Comment: @Денис Федоро, все верно. Только вот внутренние мысли не есть подлинние выражения.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: Как только мне становилось хорошо и я начинал думать: «Ах, как же хорошо»,  жизнь снова окунала меня в грязь.

Правило таково. Независимо от места, занимаемого по отношению к авторским словам, кавычками выделяется внутренняя речь, невысказанные мысли: Смотрю вслед ему и думаю:«Зачем живут такие люди?» (М.Г.); «Что-то в ней есть жалкое всё-таки», — подумал я (Ч.).

См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь, Д.Э.

Comment: Благодарю, жаль интриги не случилось. Просто я не люблю в середине предложения так мучится с пунктуацией - двоеточие и заглавная буква все сильно портит...

Comment: Вы оказались неправы!

Comment: В чем именно неправ?

Comment: 3) Дословное высказывание в качестве члена предложения (дополнения): Как только мне становилось хорошо и я начинал думать "ах, как же хорошо!", жизнь снова окунала меня в грязь.