# Пунктуация в "скрытой" прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

Правильно ли написано данное предложение с точки зрения пунктуации, или всё же требуется выделение прямой речи?

> Роман Петрович, как он любил про себя говорить, умнейший человек на
>   земле.

UpDATE. Я, честно сказать, удивлен. Прямая речь "умнейший человек на земле".

Comment: Что же здесь является прямой речью? Пока вижу только предложение , осложнённое  вводным предложением  как он любил про себя говорить

Comment: Я обновил пост.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из [ответа Арины](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/433877/177163) в другой теме предполагаю следующий вариант ответа на свой вопрос:

> Роман Петрович, как он любил про себя говорить, "умнейший человек на
>   земле".

Я прав?

Comment: Для начала разберетись, где у вас прямая речь, а где слова автора.

Comment: Я обновил в посте, но, мне казалось, все было понятно.

Answer (score 4):

**1) Передача автором содержания высказывания персонажа**

Роман Петрович, **как он любил про себя говорить**, умнейший человек на земле.

Это вводное предложение со значением источника информации. Дословность выражения не гарантируется.

Розенталь: [Вводные предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=124#pp124)

Мне помогал маляр, или, как он сам называл себя, подрядчик малярных работ (Ч.);

**2) Цитирование**

Роман Петрович, по его собственным словам, "умнейший человек на земле".

Это дословное высказывание.

ПАС [Выделение кавычками цитат и «чужих» слов](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)

Кавычками выделяются чужие слова, включенные в авторский текст, когда обозначается их принадлежность другому лицу: Это произошло весной 1901 года, который Блок назвал «исключительно важным»

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно. Вот аналогичный пример из справочника "Трудные случаи пункруации", Розенталь, Былинский.

**Аркадий Павлыч, говоря собственными его словами, «строг, но справедлив» (Тургенев).**

Answer (score 2):

Здесь уместно говорить не о прямой, а о косвенной речи.

**Роман Петрович, как он любил про себя говорить, умнейший человек на земле.**

(Аналогично: *Роман Петрович любил про себя говорить, что он умнейший человек на земле.*)

Но форма косвенной речи не гарантирует, что Роман Петрович выражался именно этими словами.

Если вы хотите подчеркнуть, что "умнейший человек на земле" — подлинные слова Романа Петровича, заключите их в кавычки:

**Роман Петрович, как он любил про себя говорить, "умнейший человек на земле".**

*Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Гоголь); Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», все больше собирало сторонников (Фадеев); Он вспомнил пословицу «Не плюй в колодец...» и отошел в сторону; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание* ([Розенталь](https://unotices.com/book.php?id=121473&page=55))